# animared plot two different colors and shapes in 3d in matplotlib python

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, plot, 3d

i try to animate two different classes "red dots" and "blue triangles". At the beginning they are all on the x-y plane and through the animation all of them should move along the z-axis. At the end it should look like on the picture.

[image]

I reached what i want in two seperate figures

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

np.random.seed(19680801)
n = 200
breite=20

def randrange(n, vmin, vmax):
    '''
    Helper function to make an array of random numbers having shape (n, )
    with each number distributed Uniform(vmin, vmax).
    '''
    return (vmax - vmin)*np.random.rand(n) + vmin

def fun_ebene(x, y):
    return x+y-breite**2/2

#function for points
def fun_punkte(x,y):
    return -x**2

# min and max of the plane
maximum=-99999.9
minimum=99999.9
for x in randrange(n, -breite, breite):
    for y in randrange(n, -breite, breite):       
        maximum=max(maximum,fun_ebene(x,y))
        minimum=min(minimum,fun_ebene(x,y))

# cache that the points not touch the plane
cache=(maximum-minimum)/10

#generate points
xs = randrange(n, -breite, breite)
ys = randrange(n, -breite, breite)
zs = randrange(n, fun_punkte(xs,ys)+cache, maximum)
zs=fun_punkte(xs,ys)
axlistxs = []
axlistys = []
axlistzs = []
bxlistxs = []
bxlistys = []
bxlistzs = []

 #seperates Data in two lists
 for i in range(len(zs)):
    if zs[i]<=fun_ebene(xs[i],ys[i]):
        axlistxs.append(xs[i])
        axlistys.append(ys[i])        
        axlistzs.append(zs[i])
    else:  
        bxlistxs.append(xs[i])
        bxlistys.append(ys[i])        
        bxlistzs.append(zs[i])

fig = plt.figure()
fig2 = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
bx = fig2.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

#set limes for the coordinate system
ax.set_xlim(-22,22)
ax.set_ylim(-22,22)
ax.set_zlim(0, -400)
bx.set_xlim(-22,22)
bx.set_ylim(-22,22)
bx.set_zlim(0, -400)

def _update_plot(i, fig, scat):
    axlistzs = []
    # sets the z-coordinate +1 every frame
    for date in range(0, len(axlistxs)):
         axlistzs.append(-i)
    list1 =[]
    list1.append(axlistxs) #x-coordinates
    list1.append(axlistys) #y-coordinates
    list1.append(axlistzs) #z-coordinates
    scat._offsets3d = (*np.array(list1),)
    return scat

def _update_plot2(i, fig, scat2):
    bxlistzs = []
    for  data in range(0, len(bxlistxs)):
        bxlistzs.append(-i)
    list2 = []
    list2.append(bxlistxs) #x-coordinates
    list2.append(bxlistys) #y-coordinates
    list2.append(bxlistzs) #z-coordinates
    np.array(list2)
    scat2._offsets3d = (*np.array(list2),)
    return scat2

#plot data
scat = ax.scatter([], [], color='red', marker='o') 
scat2 = bx.scatter([], [], color = 'blue', marker = '^')

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, _update_plot, fargs=(fig, scat),    
frames=100, interval=100)

anim2 = animation.FuncAnimation(fig2, _update_plot2, fargs=(fig2, scat2),  
frames=100, interval=100)

plt.show()
```

my problem is that i want all that in only one figure/animation. But i don't know how to scatter two different colors and shapes. in the update function i use:

```
scat._offsets3d = (*np.array(list1),)
```

to update a list of multiple x.y.z-coordinates, after that the data gets scattered by

```
scat = ax.scatter([], [], color='red', marker='o')
```

I see there no possibility to plot two different lists of classes in different colors and shapes in one figure. i hope somebody can help.

Comment: I have severe problems understanding the issue. If you want to have one figure and one animation, why do you create 2 figures and 2 animations. Remove those and you'll be fine.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't knwo how to move different objects (here: triangles and points) in one figure. Perhap it's easy, but i don't get it.

Comment: The first step towards showing it all in one figure it of course to remove the second figure from the code. You then also only need one single `FuncAnimation` and one single updating function. ...and that's it. Animating a single figure is really much simpler than animating two different ones. Of course if you have done those steps and still have a problem you may edit your question to specifically ask for that problem.

Comment: Thank you. I have now soled the problem with a colormap in the scatter command

Answer (score 1):

As said repeatedly in the comments, you need to remove the second figure from the code. You then also only need one single FuncAnimation and one single updating function. I left the rest of the code unchanged (although there might be room for optimizations as well) in order for you to see that this is really just about removing the second figure and all its dependencies from the script.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

np.random.seed(19680801)
n = 200
breite=20

def randrange(n, vmin, vmax):
    '''
    Helper function to make an array of random numbers having shape (n, )
    with each number distributed Uniform(vmin, vmax).
    '''
    return (vmax - vmin)*np.random.rand(n) + vmin

def fun_ebene(x, y):
    return x+y-breite**2/2

#function for points
def fun_punkte(x,y):
    return -x**2

# min and max of the plane
maximum=-99999.9
minimum=99999.9
for x in randrange(n, -breite, breite):
    for y in randrange(n, -breite, breite):       
        maximum=max(maximum,fun_ebene(x,y))
        minimum=min(minimum,fun_ebene(x,y))

# cache that the points not touch the plane
cache=(maximum-minimum)/10

#generate points
xs = randrange(n, -breite, breite)
ys = randrange(n, -breite, breite)
zs = randrange(n, fun_punkte(xs,ys)+cache, maximum)
zs=fun_punkte(xs,ys)
axlistxs = []
axlistys = []
axlistzs = []
bxlistxs = []
bxlistys = []
bxlistzs = []

#seperates Data in two lists
for i in range(len(zs)):
    if zs[i]<=fun_ebene(xs[i],ys[i]):
        axlistxs.append(xs[i])
        axlistys.append(ys[i])        
        axlistzs.append(zs[i])
    else:  
        bxlistxs.append(xs[i])
        bxlistys.append(ys[i])        
        bxlistzs.append(zs[i])

# only one figure and one axes
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')


ax.set_xlim(-22,22)
ax.set_ylim(-22,22)
ax.set_zlim(0, -400)

# only one updating function
def _update_plot(i):
    axlistzs = []
    # sets the z-coordinate +1 every frame
    for date in range(0, len(axlistxs)):
         axlistzs.append(-i)
    scat._offsets3d = (axlistxs,axlistys,axlistzs)

    bxlistzs = []
    for  data in range(0, len(bxlistxs)):
        bxlistzs.append(-i)
    scat2._offsets3d = (bxlistxs,bxlistys,bxlistzs)

#plot data to the same axes
scat = ax.scatter([], [], color='red', marker='o') 
scat2 = ax.scatter([], [], color = 'blue', marker = '^')

# only one FuncAnimation
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, _update_plot,
                               frames=100, interval=100)


plt.show()
```